# Change the color of title

Tags: color, titles

I successfully changed a color of sections and subsections to my defined one. However I'd like to change the `\title` with the same way, but `\titlefont{•}` doesn't work (and I guess it's not supposed to). What is the **simple** way to change the `\title` color as well? I have the simplified following code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\subsectionfont{\color{astral}}
\sectionfont{\color{astral}}

\title{...}
\author{...}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle    
    \begin{abstract} ...
    \end{abstract}    
    \smallskip
    \noindent \textbf{Key words:} ...   
    \section{...}
\end{document}
```

Every help and its description is highly welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Insert the colour directly in the `\title`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{xcolor,sectsty}

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\subsectionfont{\color{astral}}
\sectionfont{\color{astral}}

\title{\color{astral} My title}
\author{An Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}

\smallskip

\noindent \textbf{Summary:}
\lipsum*[2]

\section{A section}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

---

The above suggestion may seem crude. It is, however, inserted as a part of a one-time usage macro `\title`, and therefore sufficient for the means. For a more formalized approach, you could patch the inner `\@maketitle` macro - responsible for setting up the title display:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}% <cmd>
  {\@title}% <search>
  {\color{\@titlecolor}\@title}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\newcommand{\@titlecolor}{black}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@titlecolor}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

The above code provides `\titlecolor{<color>}` which allows you to switch to colour as needed (for example, `\titlecolor{astral}` would provide the same output). This code is also dependent on the structure of `\@maketitle`, which may be different for other classes or influenced by certain packages.

---

Another (less formal) way of address a title colour change could be to only update the way `\title` handles its argument:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\renewcommand{\@title}{\color{\@titlecolor}#1}}
\newcommand{\@titlecolor}{black}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@titlecolor}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Kidding me? So that simple? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: <sarcasm>LaTeX is better than Word because LaTeX uses semantic markup.</sarcasm>

Comment: I down-voted. There has to be a better way to do this rather than explicitly writing the color command.

Comment: @Aditya: Sure. One could load [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and patch `\maketitle`, or update the `\title` command to store its contents differently. All of these go far beyond the one-time use of `\title`. I'll add the above suggestions to my answer for completeness.

Comment: @Aditya Semantic markup is a good thing, if the author just wants to write the content. Nowadays every author wants to change the appearance, hence has intermix style and content somehow. Werner has shown how to do this, which is for a beginner looking scry i think. It was asked for a simple solution, which `\title{\color{red}{title}}` provides.

Comment: @Johannes_B, my point was that this is not an ideal solution. I understand that everyone wants to use color.  Then, packages such as titlesec, sectsty or classes such as memoir, looks script, etc should provide a way to adapt the color as well. One should not need to mix content and presentation to get the look that is needed. This can also lead to subtle mis-features. What if I need  black and white title in the headers?

Comment: @Aditya Good point. If the title is re-used, the *simple* solution runs into trouble. But the use case is not as simple as before, so a more complicated is to be assumed. My point is more like: LaTeX users tell people that LaTeX is easy, but as soon as you want to have sommething customized (which is starting soon using the standard classes) it is *quite hard* (for a starter). I think our *simple solutions* are scary for most users.

Comment: You can't reuse the title in the headers without doing something additional @Aditya. After `\maketitle`, the standard classes obliterate `\title` and friends. But I agree this is not a good solution. I disagree that the alternative involves patching the internal commands as shown here. That's like saying that the alternative to writing `\section{\color{astral} ...}` is to patch `\@section` etc. It isn't.

Answer (score 5):

It is cleaner and clearer to avoid hard-coding formatting in the content of commands like `\title`. Although this is typically a once-off command in a document - if only because `\maketitle` enforces this by wiping everything - it is still best avoided, I think.

And the alternative is not the scary-looking patching of internal commands. It is, as in the case of section headings, to use a package which does the scary stuff for you. In this case `titling` specialises in customising the format of document titles.

For example:

```
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\color{astral}}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
```

This is slightly more complex than putting the colour in `\title` but not much. I started with the defaults which I copied from `titling`'s documentation:

```
\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}
```

I then simply added the colour specification following the font specification `\LARGE`.

And that's it:

[image: custom title]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,url}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty,titling}

\definecolor{astral}{RGB}{46,116,181}
\subsectionfont{\color{astral}}
\sectionfont{\color{astral}}

\pretitle{\begin{center}\LARGE\color{astral}}
\posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip 0.5em}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
  An abstract
\end{abstract}
\smallskip
\noindent \textbf{Klíčová slova:}\dots
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```